# SQLite says "no such column: rowid" when using sub-queries

Tags: sqlite

Here's a query that works fine:

```
SELECT rowid as msg_rowid, a, b, c FROM messages m1
```

And here's another one that's also fine:

```
SELECT rowid as match_rowid FROM messages m2 WHERE x LIKE '%abc%'
```

But if I put them together as follows, SQLite complains:

```
SELECT rowid as msg_rowid, a, b, c FROM messages m1
JOIN
    (SELECT rowid as match_rowid FROM messages m2 WHERE x LIKE '%abc%')
ON
    msg_rowid >= match_rowid - 10 AND msg_rowid <= match_rowid + 5
```

giving what looks like a misleading error message: `No such column: rowid`.

How can I fix this?

The query runs fine if I use a messages.timestamp field instead of rowid:

```
SELECT timestamp as msg_ts, a, b, c FROM messages m1
JOIN
    (SELECT timestamp as match_ts FROM messages m2 WHERE x LIKE '%abc%')
ON
    msg_ts >= match_ts - 10 AND msg_ts <= match_ts + 5
```

Is this a bug, or a by-design restriction on the use of `rowid`?

Comment: Can you try to alias the rowid in the subquery?

Like this : SELECT m2.rowid as match_rowid FROM messages m2 WHERE x LIKE '%abc%'

Comment: @GuZzie Whoa... aliasing it in the *subquery* does not help, but aliasing *just* the outer one, as `m1.rowid`, fixes it!

Comment: great! :D glad to hear you fixes the problem

Comment: I'm guessing the reason you have to alias it in the outer query is that in that context, `ROWID` is ambiguous -- it could refer to a column in `m1`, or a column in the subquery results. But in the subquery, there's no such ambiguity. If that's the reason, then the error message *is* misleading, as you thought.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answered by GuZzie in a comment. For some reason SQLite requires me to be explicit about the outer rowid:

```
SELECT m1.rowid as msg_rowid, a, b, c FROM messages m1
       ^^ HERE
JOIN
    (SELECT rowid as match_rowid FROM messages m2 WHERE x LIKE '%abc%')
ON
    msg_rowid >= match_rowid - 10 AND msg_rowid <= match_rowid + 5
```

Comment: "For some reason" -- see my comment above, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682398/sqlite-says-no-such-column-rowid-when-using-sub-queries#comment68721434_8682398