# SQLite Count() and Group By not getting the count of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql

I've written my SQLite query a couple different ways: 1 with a Group By and Count(), the other with a nested select that does a count().

Here's the current version:

```
Select t.A,
       t.B,
       (Select Count(*) As CurrentCount From tableB b Where b.B = t.B) As CurrentCount
From   tableA t
```

Why does this not work in SQLite, but it's working just fine (both versions actually, the other using a group by) in SQL Server/T-SQL? Is it because of the join in the sub/nested select?

Edit: Let me clarify, I'm getting 0 for a count every time...

Edit2: I tried taking out the where clause in my nested select and it still returns 0 even though I know the table has records (133 to be exact)

**Edit (Final Solution):** This was NOT a code issue, it was a data issue. It's nothing that anyone would have caught. My "refresh" script that was reading the records from SQL Server was reading all 133, but the actual insert into my SQLite database had a missing comma, therefore the table WAS empty, hence the 0 records. Sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682398/sqlite-says-no-such-column-rowid-when-using-sub-queries

Comment: @DanielE. unfortunately, it does not. As you can see, I'm prefixing with my alias for all of my columns, except the nested select. I obviously can't do it for that one...

Comment: I see that, but joining to that nested select as a table and referencing the column... although, maybe it is because you didn't name the column in the subselect??

Comment: @DanielE. I'm not joining to that nested select, the return value of that is a column. I tried adding the alias name for the column and it still doesn't work. Edit: wait, I guess I am "joining" in the where clause...

Comment: Yea that's what I mean, maybe turn it into a "realer" join with a table alias and reference the column...

Comment: @DanielE. see my Edit2, is that kind of what you are suggesting?

Comment: @ganders . . . I think you know how to fix the problem.  My best speculation is that the data types in SQLite are not what you expect, so nothing matches `b.B = t.B`.  Can you edit the question with the definitions of these columns?  Alternatively, perhaps there are no matches in the SQLite database for another reason.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you were right, it was "another reason". See my comment to the answer below...

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
Select t.A
       ,t.B
       ,b.CurrentCount
From tableA t
INNER JOIN (Select B, Count(*) [CurrentCount] From tableB b GROUP BY B) as B
    ON  b.B = t.B
```

Comment: argh, it's nothing that you would have caught. My "refresh" script that was reading the records from SQL Server was reading all 133, but the actual insert into my SQLite database had a missing comma, therefore the table WAS empty, hence the 0 records. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @ganders . . . No offense to the author, but I vote against accepting, because this answer implies that the original formulation of the query is wrong.  I would suggest that you edit the original post, adding an "EDIT" section explaining the problem which was entirely data related.

Comment: no offense taken, I wouldn't accept it either. The 0 instead of an error should have given that away.